# Angular Separating Login and App Component

Tags: angular

When the angular app loads, it should show the login component and then be navigated to the App Component on successful login.

The code follows,

**app.module.ts**

```
bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: AddUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
  {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(data => {

      if (data) 
        this.router.navigate(['/home'])


        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams:{ returnUrl: state.url }})


      return false;
    });

    return true;
  }
}
```

**AuthService**

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  private _loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  isLoggedIn = this._loggedIn.asObservable()

  login() : Observable<boolean>
  {
     this._loggedIn.next(true);

     return this.isLoggedIn
  }
}
```

But after login, it is not navigating to the Home Component and it always stays in the Login Component and the login page loads again?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-h1c2t5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Should that be an else in your `AuthGuard`?

Comment: No that doesn't work and I think something else I am missing

Comment: Can you provide a working stackblitz of the same?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-h1c2t5

Comment: I get this error on opening your stackblitz `ERROR
Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements`

Comment: @NicholasK, Could you please check it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackblitz link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-pcbnsy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

## app.module.ts  <=== if registered parent module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, LoginComponent ],
   providers: [
     AuthGuard,
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

## routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: "full"},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},

  { path: 'home', component: HelloComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

];
```

## login.component.ts

```
  login():any{

    console.log("login")

    this.authService.login(true)
   this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

## guard.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
  {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(data => {

      console.log('sssss::' + data);

      if (data) 
      {
     return true;
      }
     else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams:{ returnUrl: state.url }})
       return false;
}
    });


    return true;
  }
}
```

## auth.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, BehaviorSubject  } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  // private _loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  // isLoggedIn = this._loggedIn.asObservable()
 public isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

  login(value: boolean) 
  {
  this.isLoggedIn.next(value);

  }

  register() {

  }

  logout (){
    this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
  }


}
```